# VoiceBot To Interact With External IVR

Tags: ivr

I want to build a twilio application to interact with an external IVR system.  Note, I am not trying to build an IVR using twilio.  Rather, I am trying to interact with an IVR.  The application needs to make an outgoing call to the IVR and then send voice responses (audio) as well as receive audio from the external IVR and perform STT on these.  Ideally I'd like to do this purely using the python client and not have to create a server.

Could anyone suggest the best approach to accomplish this using Twilio.  Code examples would be highly valuable.

Thank you.